# Use function result as arglist

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins, sass-maps

Is there an intelligent way to use the function result of `map.get` as an arglist without first saving the list to a variable?

```
@use "sass:map";

@mixin make-button-size($font-size, $padding-vertical, $padding-horizontal) {
    // make-button-size implementation
}

$sizes: (
    md: (10px, 11px, 12px),
)

$params: map.get($sizes, md);
@include make-button-size($params...);
```

I tried the following, but this leads to a syntax error:

```
@include make-button-size((map.get($sizes, md))...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on https://www.sassmeister.com/ .

Even if I type the following, the error does not appear.

```
@mixin make-button-size($font-size, $padding-vertical, $padding-horizontal) {
    a: $font-size;
    b: $padding-vertical;
    c: $padding-horizontal;
}

$sizes: (
    md: (10px, 11px, 12px),
);
$params: map-get($sizes, md);

p {
  sizes: $params;
  @include make-button-size(map-get($sizes, md)...);
}
```

Compiled:

```css
p {
  sizes: 10px, 11px, 12px;
  a: 10px;
  b: 11px;
  c: 12px;
}
```

`$sizes: (...)` doesn't have a semicolon, so make sure it's not.

Comment: You're right! It seems to be a problem of PhpStorm that the SCSS code cannot be parsed, so the FileWatcher is not triggered. Thanks for your answer.